# Save single channel png file along with colormap in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Can someone give me an example how to save an single channel index image along with its color map in python?
The similar operation in Matlab would look like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47438654/single-channel-png-displayed-with-colors):

```
[img, cmap] = imread('myImg.png'); % cmap is a [256x3] 'double' array
imwrite(img, cmap, 'outfile.png');
```

I saw that `imsave` from `matplotlib.pyplot` has the option to specify a colormap (`cmap`), however I cannot figure out how to provide my own colormap along with it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
im = plt.imread('~/myImg.png')
my_cmap = np.array([(128,64,128),
                 (244,35,232),
                 (70,70,70),
                 (102,102,156),],dtype=np.float64)
plt.imsave('~/test.png',im, cmap=my_cmap)
```

gives me

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Same happens when I try a `dict` or a `list` ...

**Edit**:
Following the '[dublicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094288/convert-list-of-rgb-codes-to-matplotlib-colormap)' answer, I still get wrong colors for the output image:

```
red = my_cmap[:,0] / 255.0
green = my_cmap[:,1] / 255.0
blue = my_cmap[:,2] / 255.0
cdict = { 'red' : red, 'green' : green, 'blue' : blue }
my_cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(cdict, name='my_colormap')
plt.imsave('im_test.png',im, cmap=my_cmap)
```

Even if I switch `green` and `blue` in the example above my output image looks the same, so it seems there is still something wrong with the format...

Comment: As the name suggests, a ListedColormap will take a list of colors as input. I don't know why it should even work with a dictionary. So, just as in the duplicate provide your list as input, `my_cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(my_cmap/255.)`.

Comment: Ahh thanks a lot, now it works.