# Plotly colormaps in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I really like the [additional colormaps](https://plotly.com/python/builtin-colorscales/) like 'dense' or 'ice' from plotly. Nevertheless, I am currently using matplotlib for most of my plots.

Is there a way to use a pyplot colormap in matplotlib plots?

When I take the colormap 'ice' for example, the only thing I get is rgb color as strings with

```py
import plotly.express as px

px.colors.sequential.ice
```

This just returns

```
['rgb(3, 5, 18)',
 'rgb(25, 25, 51)',
 'rgb(44, 42, 87)',
 'rgb(58, 60, 125)',
 'rgb(62, 83, 160)',
 'rgb(62, 109, 178)',
 'rgb(72, 134, 187)',
 'rgb(89, 159, 196)',
 'rgb(114, 184, 205)',
 'rgb(149, 207, 216)',
 'rgb(192, 229, 232)',
 'rgb(234, 252, 253)']
```

The problem is, I have no idea how to use this in a matplotlib plot. The thing I tried was creating a [custom colormap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094288/convert-list-of-rgb-codes-to-matplotlib-colormap) with

```
my_cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(px.colors.sequential.ice, name='my_colormap_name')
```

but this gave me the following error when used inside a plot:

```
ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: 'rgb(3, 5, 18)'
```

Anyone knows how to convert this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decode the RGB string:

```
import plotly.express as px
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

SAMPLES = 20
ice = px.colors.sample_colorscale(px.colors.sequential.ice, SAMPLES)
rgb = [px.colors.unconvert_from_RGB_255(px.colors.unlabel_rgb(c)) for c in ice]

cmap = mcolors.ListedColormap(rgb, name='Ice', N=SAMPLES)
```

Demo:

```
import numpy as np

gradient = np.linspace(0, 1, 256)
gradient = np.vstack((gradient, gradient))
plt.imshow(gradient, aspect='auto', cmap=cmap)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, works like a charm. I've used `SAMPLES = 1000` to get a continuous looking colorbar.